# Python Requests: requests.get(url).json() Error

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

When trying to use python requests I obtain the following: when I try to ensure a request is in json format. The request when using `requests.get(url)` is `<Response [200]>`.

However when using `request.get(url).json()` I obtain the following:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Printing `requests.get(url)`.headers gives the following:

```
{'Server': 'nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Mon, 01 Apr 2019 21:03:28 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 25 Mar 2019 21:25:01 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'ETag': 'W/"5c99472d-806"', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

I've tried snipping certain characters like <, >, \, \0 but that didn't affect the outcome.

Comment: The server headers in your response show content-type is `text/html`, not `application/json`. You can see what the body contains with the `.content` attribute.

Comment: Yes, how can I go about changing this to application/json?

Comment: Your JSON seems to be using single quotes, try change the content-type to `application/json`, set the header: `Content-Type` when serving your page to `application/json`.

Comment: @PrestonHager that's not the json, that's a dict from requests representing the response headers.

Comment: How do I change the content-type?

Comment: @jordanm oops, it is. However given that the error is on char 0 it's probably a bracket or quote that's missing.

Comment: dude. Where's the url?

Answer (score 0):

Below request should work.

`import requests
requests.get(URL, headers={'content-type':'application/json'}).json()`

Comment: you can also use json.loads() to the response.

Comment: This gives the same end result :   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I can see my original content type is 'test/html' even after adding headers={'accept': 'application/json'} to my request.get arguments.